# Web-application: Two element login

Tags: security, web-applications, smartcard, biometrics

I'm developing web-application that needs very high security - one of requirements is you'll need password and second factor to gain access - for eg. token, fingerprint scanner, magnetic card etc.

My question is: Is there any resonable way for webbrowser to access data from devices like card reader or finger print scanner and send it during login proccess? Java applet, browser plugin? Something else? Or token is only option?

EDIT:
I've found something about two-way certificate auth where client and server exchanges thier certificates - it seems it's possible for client certificate to be secured with smart card, so user has to put it in reader during login process. Maybe someone knows something more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a web application I would suggest using mobile phones.
When a user tries to log in he/she gets a text message that he has to enter in addition to his password.

There are numerous service providers that offer sending text messages via simple REST API's for an affordable fee. When security is a big concern that extra cost should not be a big issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm considering that too(we're even using thing like this for different purposes). Main problem is we're talking about admin side of PCI DSS compliant application so securitity and stability is really critical here - involving third party company may cause some problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid to interact with external hardware you are stuck with writing a native browser plugin or ActiveX control (in the case of IE). However, some magnetic card readers will actually behave like a keyboard (i.e. they will "type" out the data they read from the card followed by some sort of control character like \n) - so with some focus() trickery, you could conceivably capture the input of the reader without using anything but pure JS.

Comment: Thanks - native plugins are one of considered options - but they have some obvious cons. I'm currently reading about smart cards - it's not completly clear to me yet, but it appears page may request certyficate from browser with in turn needs smart card to be present in reader - maybe something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions:

- Do like some banks does, give the client a file with info needed to get in. Then encrypt the file and check the the hash of it. (maybe both sha1 and md5?) Your only concern here would be theft of the file.
- Get inspiration from steam, send verification email whenever a user logs on from a new computer (and/or browser and/or ip maybe?)
- Also, you could give the user a list of predefined keys, (via. mail, e-mail or in person) then whenever a user needs to log on, ask for a random key, and when it's used discard of it in the system. Downside is you'd have to hand out a new list when they get used up. (I've seen systems like this work very well before.)

Hope any of this is any inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for answer, idea with file is quite interesting - I'll check if it meets with other conditions. Steam-inspiration is good for security too, but unfortunately that has to be two elements every time(exactly described in spec. as password and something you have or something you are - with means biometric). Problem with list is that this type of access is mentioned for administration pourposes so we can't risk running out of passwords and waiting until new list arrives.

Comment: For running out of passwords in the list idea, generate 100 keys, whenever only 20 or so is left, give next list that will step in as soon as the old list is used up.

Comment: Normally you would be right, but we have quite huge distance beetwen authorized persons and mail services are not exactly trademark of my country :) But of course I appreciate ideas.

Comment: I see. :) Another method i sometimes use my self for admin login, is not having the login form on the server, but on the client side. (HTML) It doesn't really do much but hide the login form from other people, but still. :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might consider is implementing something akin to Blizzard's Authenticator for World of Warcraft. It's an 8-digit code that changes every 60 seconds and is tied to a specific serial number.  You'd store the serial with the user account record and compute the expected code based on that and the current time. It's a system that's stood against a veritable armada of highly-motivated hackers, so at least it's reasonably secure.

The main benefit is that you don't have to directly interface with the hardware and the user can authenticate from anywhere. The downside is that you don't have the same feeling of safety as with checking physical hardware.

Comment: yup, it's called security token and may be used in this project, but as you noticed they have some downsides. It's possible I end up with this, but I think other possibilities are worth considering(and much more interesting from developers point of view :))